# Durable vs Mirrored Queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

My queues are durable and Messages are persistent. I have setup 3 RabbitMQ Server Cluster having HA mirroring of all queues among all servers. My Master node seems to be Rabbitmq3 When I shutdown RabbitmQ3. I get following errors.

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@rabbitmq3' of durable queue 'durable-test-queue' in vhost 'test' is down or inaccessible
```

I think if I have mirrored queues in Cluster. I should not create durable queue since they will cause problem if my rabbitmq master node goes down suddenly

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a cluster - you system should tolerate failure of any single node, including queue master. Your error is just a notification that current master is down. Cluster should elect new master and queue should continue to function, regardless of durability of the queue / persistence of messages.

You should be able to continue to send/receive messages on those durable queues.